# How to solve this third order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, python, mathematica

I need help to solve the following differential equation:

$$A^{'''}y + A^{''}(-1 - y\cot{y}) - \frac{2A^{'}}{y} + \frac{2A}{y^{2}}(3+y\cot{y}) = 0$$

where $A$ is a function of $y$ and $A'$ represents the derivative of $A$ with respect to $y$.

---

What I have tried:

- Using DSolve in Mathematica (It does not work but simply returns the original input)
- Using Sympy package in Python (Also does not work but returns an error also)

I can see nothing wrong with my code (see attached pictures) and I have no idea how to solve such an equation by hand. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Python Sympy Attempt]

[image: Mathematica Attempt]

See code below:

```
from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex=True)
from sympy import *
import sympy as sp

y = sp.Symbol('y')

a =sp.Function('a')(y)

diffeq = Eq(a.diff(y,y,y)*y + a.diff(y,y)*(-1-y*sp.cot(y)) - 2*a/y + (2*a/y**2)*(3+y*sp.cot(y)),0)

display(diffeq)

dsolve(diffeq,a)
```

Comment: Please embed the SymPy code.  If you ask SymPy to output $\TeX$, you can also embed the output.

Comment: It is entirely plausible that there simply isn't a closed-form solution to this function.  Numerical techniques or approximate techniques may be needed instead.  Do you have some reason to believe that there *is* a closed-form solution to this equation?

Comment: I know in fact that there is a nice solution. The equation comes from a paper that Im trying to understand

Comment: You haven't embedded all output in text format. If Imgur goes down, your question becomes kind of useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general easy approach for higher order equations with non-constant coefficients. However taking a close look at the coefficients one observes that they have descending power in $y$ and therefore it is a good idea to *try* monomials as solutions. Indeed, setting $A=y^n$ gives
$$
(n+1)(n-2)y^{n-2}(-y\cot(y)+n-3)=0
$$
which gives to fundamental solutions namely $A_1=y^2$ and $A_2=\tfrac{1}{y}$.

To find the third solution we can reduce the order of the differential equation using Abel's theorem $W=c\cdot e^{\int 1/y+\cot(y) dy}$ where $W$ denotes the Wronskian comprised of the two known solutions and a placeholder $A_3$ for the missing one. This leads to an order reduction namely
$$
3y^2A''_3(y)-6A_3(y) = c\cdot y^3\sin(y)
$$
I hope this answers your question.

Additional note: I do not have access to Mathematica but Maple was able to compute the solutions without a problem so maybe you did have an Input error after all?

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps me understand a lot better.

Just one quick question. There should be three constants of integration in the solution. Where would the third constant be? It seems like A1 and A2 are contained in A3.

Thank you again!

Comment: You are welcome! It's the $c$ on the right hand side of the last equation.